# How to have togglebutton take the whole space in a container?

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout

I'm trying to achieve a flexible behaviour from the togglebutton, my togglebutton is inside a container with a height of 60px and infinte width, how can get the toggle button to take up all the available space?

Sadly I can't use MediaQuery as using it breaks my dropdown functionality somehow, is there any other way?

here is my code for toggle button:

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10),
                ),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(108, 101, 172, 1),
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 60,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                child: ToggleButtons(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                 textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 17,
                  ),
                  selectedColor: Colors.black,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('My country'),
                    Text('Global'),
                  ],
                  onPressed: (int index) {
                    setState(() {
                      for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                          buttonIndex < isSelected.length;
                          buttonIndex++) {
                        if (buttonIndex == index) {
                          isSelected[buttonIndex] = true;
                        } else {
                          isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
                        }
                      }

                      if (index == 1) {
                        getGlobalResult();
                        isGlobal = true;
                        isTotal = true;
                      } else {
                        getCountryTotalResult(selectedValue);
                        isGlobal = false;
                        isTotal = true;
                        isDaySelected = [true, false, false];
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  isSelected: isSelected,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

this is what I get,

[image: togglebutton]

what i want to achieve(did this with constraints)
[image: togglebutton]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the full width ToggleButtons you can use `LayoutBuilder`.

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => ToggleButtons(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: constraints.maxWidth/2),
    ....
    Your CODE
    ....
  )
);
```

This will dynamically expand your `ToggleButtons` to full width.

Comment: it's `expand`,  just in case someone gets and error. Thanks

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla corrected

Answer (score -1):

The best way for my case is using SizedBox:

1. First solution:

> ```
> SizedBox(
>   width: double.infinity,
>   child: YourToggleButtons,
> )
> ```

2. Second solution:

> ```
> SizedBox.expand(
>   child: new YourToggleButtons,
> )
> ```